# How to delete inodes in ec2 volume?

Tags: ubuntu

Can any one please tel me how to delete some inodes from my current volume

```
         df -i
         Filesystem      Inodes   IUsed  IFree IUse% Mounted on
         /dev/xvda1     1310720 1310719      1  100% /
```

I am not able to create any file in drive but i have space in my drive

```
df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1       20G  6.3G   13G  34% /
```

can any one help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Inode is related to no. of files in that drive. If you have more no of small files, even you have free space, you could not create files further. You could add a volume drive and mount on any directory under / and move some files to that directory to relase some inodes.

Comment: But how u can do for a ebs/root volume

Comment: You can attach an ebs volume to your existing instance. After attach create filesystem and mount as usual what we do in normal systems, find   below links for further info.http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-attaching-volume.html and http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html. After mounting the volume, move files to that drive. This will automatically free the inodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the solution but could not get time to update this case.

Here is what was happening in back end.

Session files were creating under

> /var/lib/php5/

and those file size was zero bytes.So whenever files were creating it was consuming the inodes.

Wrote one small shell script to remove those and at the end my problems also solved..Please find the script mentioned below:

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /var/lib/php5
sudo find . -name 'sess*' -size 0 -print0 | xargs -0 sudo rm
sudo find . -name 'sess*' -ctime +2 -print0 | xargs -0 sudo rm
```

Comment: For anyone finding this with similar problem. make sure php session.gc_probability is set to 1 so php can automatically delete old session files.

Answer (score 0):

One of the things that takes up a lot of inodes on ubuntu servers is old kernel packages, you may be able to free up a lot of inodes with `sudo apt autoremove` (or `sudo apt-get autoremove`)